# Message appending in alertdialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a alertdialog box with the linkbutton and ok button.
when the error is generated the message is displayed on alertdialog box.
But when the new error is generated the new message is getting appended with the old message and link button is getting repeated too.
I want to delete the old message and display only new message.

the code snippet is below

```
    function AlertDialog(msg) {
        var newMsg=msg;
        if(msg==="SessionTimeOut")
            newMsg="@Resources.commonResources.SessionTimeOut";

        $("#dialog-showMsg").text=" ";
        $("#dialog-showMsg #sp").append(newMsg,"<br/>","<br/>")
        $("#dialog-showMsg").dialog(
            open: function(event, ui){
            $('<a />', {
                'class': 'linkClass',
                text: 'Details',
                href: '#'
            })
            .appendTo($(".ui-dialog-content"))          //use buttonpane to display link at bottom     content
            .click(function(){
                $(event.target).dialog('close');
            });
    },
               position:{my: "center", at: "center"},
               draggable: true,
               height: 300,
               width: 260,
               show: { effect: "Fold" },
               hide: { effect: "Fold" },
               modal: true,
               buttons: {
                  OK: function() {
                  if(msg==="SessionTimeOut")
                  {window.location.href=" /" + "@AppName";}
                  $(this).dialog("close");}
               },

           });
           return true;
}
```

[sample images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWXPF.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending content using jquery, based on [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

> The .append() and .appendTo() methods perform the same task. The major
>   difference is in the syntax-specifically, in the placement of the
>   content and target. With .append() , the selector expression preceding
>   the method is the container into which the content is inserted.

Instead of using append, you should use html injector like this one.

```
$("#dialog-showMsg").text=" ";
$("#dialog-showMsg #sp").html("<br/>"+newMsg+"<br/>");
```

or if you don't want to use html() you can remove the content at first like this one

```
$("#dialog-showMsg").text=" ";
$("#dialog-showMsg #sp").empty();
$("#dialog-showMsg #sp").append(newMsg,"<br/>","<br/>");
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You are appending message with old one. That's why it is happening. Instead of append, you can use html, than it will work.

```
$("#dialog-showMsg #sp").html(newMsg,"<br/>","<br/>")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are appending the message that is the reason 
Use

```
 $("#dialog-showMsg #sp").html(newMsg,"<br/>","<br/>")
```

**instead of**

```
 $("#dialog-showMsg #sp").append(newMsg,"<br/>","<br/>")**
```

Answer (score 0):

because you use `append`

`append` will merge old content with new content

so use `html` instead of `append` like,

```
$("#dialog-showMsg #sp").html(newMsg,"<br/>","<br/>")
```